# Access Array Data

Tags: php

Have the following output from an array:

```
Array ( [error] => Array ( ) [result] => Array ( [XXBTZUSD] => Array ( [a] => Array ( [0] => 9506.50000
```

Need to access the [0] value that is 9506.50. How can I isolate that aspect of the array into a variable.

Comment: "How can I put that in a php variable" it is already in a php varaible

Comment: I will edit it. It was a quick question. Thank you for pointing that out! @nogad

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$var = $data["result"]["XXBTZUSD"]["a"][0]
```

Read more about [PHP arrays here](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php).

If you want exactly "9506.50", use [number_format](http://php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php):

```
echo number_format($var, 2, '.', '');
```

Comment: amazing support klenium. Thank you for being awesome! Great addition with that number_format.